# Update vf emailTemplate from a VF page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, visualforce-template

is it possible to update a visualforce emailTemplate from via a Visualforce page?
I have a user who is not admin, and user should be able to edit/update the visualforce email template.

thanks a ton.

Comment: Visualforce email templates can get pretty sophisticated and need testing - this is probably why SFDC chose that one needs Customize Application privileges. How would the user test the edited template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the non-sys admin user just wants to update the content of the email, such as subject, body, various sections, images etc, then you could hold this in a custom object record. The visualforce template can just fetch these details and display the content on the email.
You can have different records for different email templates.

The same could be done in Labels as well, but that would again require "customize application" privileges, which I don't think you are willing to give.